# Is it possible to print Fibonacci series in java without using recursion, loop and custom function

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have been trying various methods. However I cannot find out whether it is possible to print Fibonacci series in java without using recursion, loop and custom functions. If yes then how?

Comment: of course just print `System.out.println ("1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 8 , 13 , 21 , 34 , 55 , 89");` - Not what you are wanting is it?

Comment: @Jameson The link you posted has a loop.

Comment: @Jameson the link has a custom function.

Comment: @ScaryWombat exactly my teacher has given me this peculiar assignment, I guess I need to delete this question

Comment: Are you allowed to use code?

Comment: @shmosel yes simple code

Comment: @Jameson The link you posted has recursion. It fails all three of the OP's conditions.

Comment: @EJP Your statement is factually incorrect. Please re-evaluate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the scheduled exector pool. It's not technically a loop, though it is using the repeating thread to behave like a loop.

```
private static volatile int currentNum = 1;
private static volatile int previousNum = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor timer = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    timer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        System.out.println(currentNum);
        int temp = currentNum;
        currentNum += previousNum;
        if (currentNum < 0) {
            // overflow
            timer.shutdown();
        }
        previousNum = temp;
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: This solution has a 'custom function': a `run()` method, although admittedly it is implicit.

Comment: True...but without that it basically leaves the hard coded println solution :-)